# Kohana 3. Join with multiple condition using OR

Tags: join, kohana, query-builder, kohana-3.3

I'm using Kohana Query Builder and trying do next:

```
$query
 ->join(«t1», «INNER»)
 ->on(«t1.id»,»=»,»t2.parent_id»)
 ->on(«t1.id»,»=»,»t3.x_id»)
```

This means:

```
INNER JOIN t1
ON(t1.id = t2.parent_id AND t1.id = t3.x_id)
```

But how force to use **OR** instead of **AND** of KO3 query builder join methods?

```
INNER JOIN t1
ON(t1.id = t2.parent_id OR t1.id = t3.x_id)
```

Comment: The [`Database_Query_Builder_Join`'s `compile()` method](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/Database_Query_Builder_Join#compile) seems to have `AND` hardcoded. So you either need to write/find your own Query_Builder or not use one at all I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to Konaha source code all `on()` methods are concatinated with `AND`:

```
// Concat the conditions "... AND ..."
$sql .= ' ON ('.implode(' AND ', $conditions).')';
```

So you have at least 2 ways:

- Redifine `Database_Query_Builder_Join` methods to support `OR` concatinator
- (it's cheating) Use `DB::expr()` as 3rd parameter to `on()` method like:

  `->on('t1.id', '=', DB::expr('t2.parent_id OR t1.id = t3.x_id))`

Comment: DB::expr().. Why I didn't think about it earlier? Great, thanks!